# Low saturation and blurred fonts when using a 60Hz adapter vs a 30Hz adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, 4k

I have a MacBook Pro 16", 2019. I recently bought a new screen (LG 27GP950) which I connected using an HDMI cable through a USB-C -> HDMI adapter. It worked fine, but the adapter was capped to 30Hz.

I bought a new adapter that was is capped at 60Hz, but now some applications have noticeably lower contrast for text and some coloured fonts (particularly red) are very blurry. An example application is Visual Studio Code.

I've used a 4K screen at 60Hz before with this laptop (LG 27UL850 connected through USB-C) which worked fine, so I don't think the laptop is struggling to drive it.

I have tried different cables, I tried replacing the adapter too to make sure it wasn't faulty. I've also tried another 16" to check it's not the laptop. None of these things worked.

Is anyone aware of what may be causing this and how I can rectify/troubleshoot it?

Here are some examples of the same app and text but using the two different adapters:

[image: 60Hz blurry example]

[image: 30Hz crisp example]

Comment: The LG 27GP950 supports DisplayPort, as does the MBP, so don't waste your time with HDMI adapters.

Comment: The screen only has a single displayport input and I'm using it for another pc connected. As far as I understand a HDMI 2.1 port shouldn't have any problems with a MBP.

Comment: Adapters are typically junk, but you gotta do what you gotta do.